# Can I make Finder NOT ignore leading zeros sorting by name?

Tags: finder, sort

I understand Apple's intention to sort things like this:

```
dir_1
dir_002
dir_03
...
```

But it becomes ridiculous in the following example:

```
dir_0.1_1
dir_0.01_1
dir_0.001_1
dir_0.1_2
dir_0.01_2
dir_0.001_2
...
```

How can I make Finder not ignore leading zeros when it's sorting by name?

Thank you.

Comment: In Finder, in Column view it is as it is (that is, other then the Finder preference "Keep folders on top when sorting by name" if the version of macOS you're running supports it), in List view, you can click the Name column to change the alphabetical direction and that's it (that is, other then the Finder preference "Keep folders on top when sorting by name" if the version of macOS you're running supports it). If you want some other form of sorting not provided by Finder, then you'll need to use a third-party file manager that has the capabilities you'd like.

Comment: So, in short, it's no, right? Thank you for your reply.